# Strange asp.net behavior when trying to find Radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

The following code works pretty well to loop through all radio buttons in a container(in this case a div)

```
foreach (RadioButton rb in divContainer.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
   ....
```

Lets call these `rb1,rb2,rb3` which belong to GroupName A

Now if we put another set of radio buttons(`rb4,rb5,rb6`) inside this Div and assign them a different group(b), The same code still only loops through the `rb1,rb2,rb3`.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: make sure it is not a browser cache problem... clear history and try again

Comment: how do you add the radio buttons? hardcode them or add them programatically?

Comment: No, add them in HTML